# Why html skips my variable and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, html, django

The whole point is that "{{some_variable}}" just disappears in my work, while that not happens in any other example (that i could find)

views.py

```
def home(request):
data = {
    'title':'Main page'
}
```

home.html

```
<title>{{ title }}</title>
```

browser page => show code

```
<title></title>
```

Why he just skipped **title**? It definitely worked in the tutorial.

I'm trying to achieve page title being "Main page", but i want to do it by reffering to title dictionary.

I'm saying about tutorial as example of the same code, that worked. But if anyone needs to watch smth similar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDwdMDQ8oX4 16:00

**And my thanks goes to...**

**furas** *(Please write it as answer, I need to tick it)*

I did

```
return render(request, 'blog/home.html')
```

But I should

```
return render(request, 'blog/home.html', data)
```

*(And of course I didn't mention main problem in my code)*

Comment: What tutorial are you referring to?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Which tutorial? Please be clearer.

Comment: Please show the rest of that view.

Comment: you have to use `data` in `render(..., "template.html", data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorial is just fine, it uses [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#template-inheritance), [render ()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function and [variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#variables)